# Механизм cookies

Tags: cookie, php, http

Кто мне может простым текстом объяснить как действуют cookies??

Я напишу как я это понимаю ,а Вы скажите верно ли я думаю или поправьте:
Когда произошла авторизация, с сервера на компьютер с помощью функции setcookies или другой создаются cookies и дальше каждый раз , когда я открываю следующую страницу на сайте сервер проверяет cookie на моем компьютере, так?

Answer (score 3):

Авторизация - не обязательное условие для использования cookies. Условно - это переменные (пары имя-значение), хранящиеся на стороне клиента (в браузере)

На стороне сервера при формировании ответа в заголовок можно добавить команду на установку значения этих переменных

```
Set-Cookie: name=value
```

При получении ответа браузер разбирает заголовки и если встречается заголовок Set-Cookie,
создает эти "переменные" с указанными для них параметрами.

При выполнении запросов клиент (браузер) также в каждом заголовке запроса отправляет их:

```
Cookie:name=value;
```

При установке кукам задается домен, путь (они могут устанавливаться как для отдельных страниц, так и для всего сайта) и время жизни. Поэтому при запросах на сервер браузером отдаются только "нужные" cookies

В PHP для формирования cookies есть функция [setcookie()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php), которая формирует соответствующую запись в заголовках ответа, а также суперглобальный массив [$_COOKIES](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.cookies.php), который автоматически заполняется после получения запроса данными из заголовков.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю автору интересно услышать именно механизм авторизации. Да, **vanchester** хорошо показал что такое cookies. А вот авторизацию чаще всего делают средствами сессий. При выполнении функции session_start в cookies попадает PHPSESSID с индетефикатором сессии. Если в куках уже есть PHPSESSID, то session_start передаст индетефикатор сессии обработчику сессий (на хостинге) и передаст нам $_SESSION с сохранёнными переменными.